# TRYING TO VERIFY MY SOURCE CODE ON ETHERSCAN ErrorUnable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])

Tags: error, bytecode, compiler, contract-verification, parser

Compiler Warning(s): ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
--> myc:1:1:
|
1 | "accounts": {
| ^^^^^^^^^^
Compiler Version: v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7
Optimization Enabled: False
Runs: 200

ByteCode (what we are looking for):

My contract info

Here is my transaction hash: 0xfe5a4cbce790ff76aea3cab9221d24b9274205e1090ae2b25ea74ef2f7c1b55f

Block Number: 13832997

From: 0xe8bda41beb33aa42bdc5eb6c7eaadd38ecbdc5ed

Interacted to: 0xf3e0e047807ba8dd53c7cd67776cd6dc9047b7cb

input data 0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000066f8d7699d5759e43a1d9793e7c33ff803b409e9000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c91446b0a1af1f50f00000

url to contract https://etherscan.io/token/0xf3e0e047807ba8dd53c7cd67776cd6dc9047b7cb

source code

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (token/ERC20/presets/ERC20PresetFixedSupply.sol)
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

```
import "../extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";


/**
 * @dev {ERC20} token, including:
 *
 *  - Preminted initial supply
 *  - Ability for holders to burn (destroy) their tokens
 *  - No access control mechanism (for minting/pausing) and hence no governance
 *
 * This contract uses {ERC20Burnable} to include burn capabilities - head to
 * its documentation for details.
 *
 * _Available since v3.4._
 *
 * _Deprecated in favor of https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/[Contracts Wizard]._
 */
contract ERC20PresetFixedSupply is ERC20Burnable {
    /**
     * @dev Mints `initialSupply` amount of token and transfers them to `owner`.
     *
     * See {ERC20-constructor}.
     */
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address owner
    ) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(owner, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

then a source code with the token name in it:

"accounts": {
"account{0}": "0xE8bda41BEB33aa42bdc5EB6c7EaaDd38eCBdc5ED"
},
"linkReferences": {},
"transactions": [
{
"timestamp": 1639916407226,
"record": {
"value": "0",
"parameters": [
"traceroute woke_mind_virus",
"Virus_of_the_Mind",
"210000000000000000000000000",
"0xE8bda41BEB33aa42bdc5EB6c7EaaDd38eCBdc5ED"
],
"abi": "0x55507316a2ecd9b9a32d4209f43d612bbce4b1cca44a7e1b861fa3b3fcce0de5",
"contractName": "ERC20PresetFixedSupply",
"bytecode": "60806040523480156200001157600080fd5b5060405162001fe038038062001fe0833981810160405281019062000037919062000368565b83838160039080519060200190620000519291906200020c565b5080600490805190602001906200006a9291906200020c565b5050506200007f81836200008960201b60201c565b505050506200074b565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff161415620000fc576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401620000f39062000450565b60405180910390fd5b62000110600083836200020260201b60201c565b8060026000828254620001249190620004ff565b92505081905550806000808473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060008282546200017b9190620004ff565b925050819055508173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff167fddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef83604051620001e2919062000472565b60405180910390a3620001fe600083836200020760201b60201c565b5050565b505050565b505050565b8280546200021a90620005d0565b90600052602060002090601f0160209004810192826200023e57600085556200028a565b82601f106200025957805160ff19168380011785556200028a565b828001600101855582156200028a579182015b82811115620002895782518255916020019190600101906200026c565b5b5090506200029991906200029d565b5090565b5b80821115620002b85760008160009055506001016200029e565b5090565b6000620002d3620002cd84620004b8565b6200048f565b905082815260208101848484011115620002f257620002f1620006ce565b5b620002ff8482856200059a565b509392505050565b600081519050620003188162000717565b92915050565b600082601f830112620003365762000335620006c9565b5b815162000348848260208601620002bc565b91505092915050565b600081519050620003628162000731565b92915050565b60008060008060808587031215620003855762000384620006d8565b5b600085015167ffffffffffffffff811115620003a657620003a5620006d3565b5b620003b4878288016200031e565b945050602085015167ffffffffffffffff811115620003d857620003d7620006d3565b5b620003e6878288016200031e565b9350506040620003f98782880162000351565b92505060606200040c8782880162000307565b91505092959194509250565b600062000427601f83620004ee565b91506200043482620006ee565b602082019050919050565b6200044a8162000590565b82525050565b600060208201905081810360008301526200046b8162000418565b9050919050565b60006020820190506200048960008301846200043f565b92915050565b60006200049b620004ae565b9050620004a9828262000606565b919050565b6000604051905090565b600067ffffffffffffffff821115620004d657620004d56200069a565b5b620004e182620006dd565b9050602081019050919050565b600082825260208201905092915050565b60006200050c8262000590565b9150620005198362000590565b9250827fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff038211156200055157620005506200063c565b5b828201905092915050565b6000620005698262000570565b9050919050565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff82169050919050565b6000819050919050565b60005b83811015620005ba5780820151818401526020810190506200059d565b83811115620005ca576000848401525b50505050565b60006002820490506001821680620005e957607f821691505b602082108114156200060057620005ff6200066b565b5b50919050565b6200061182620006dd565b810181811067ffffffffffffffff821117156200063357620006326200069a565b5b80604052505050565b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052601160045260246000fd5b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052602260045260246000fd5b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052604160045260246000fd5b600080fd5b600080fd5b600080fd5b600080fd5b6000601f19601f8301169050919050565b7f45524332303a206d696e7420746f20746865207a65726f206164647265737300600082015250565b62000722816200055c565b81146200072e57600080fd5b50565b6200073c8162000590565b81146200074857600080fd5b50565b611885806200075b6000396000f3fe608060405234801561001057600080fd5b50600436106100cf5760003560e01c806342966c681161008c57806395d89b411161006657806395d89b4114610226578063a457c2d714610244578063a9059cbb14610274578063dd62ed3e146102a4576100cf565b806342966c68146101be57806370a08231146101da57806379cc67901461020a576100cf565b806306fdde03146100d4578063095ea7b3146100f257806318160ddd1461012257806323b872dd14610140578063313ce56714610170578063395093511461018e575b600080fd5b6100dc6102d4565b6040516100e9919061119f565b60405180910390f35b61010c60048036038101906101079190610f53565b610366565b6040516101199190611184565b60405180910390f35b61012a610384565b6040516101379190611301565b60405180910390f35b61015a60048036038101906101559190610f00565b61038e565b6040516101679190611184565b60405180910390f35b610178610486565b604051610185919061131c565b60405180910390f35b6101a860048036038101906101a39190610f53565b61048f565b6040516101b59190611184565b60405180910390f35b6101d860048036038101906101d39190610f93565b61053b565b005b6101f460048036038101906101ef9190610e93565b61054f565b6040516102019190611301565b60405180910390f35b610224600480360381019061021f9190610f53565b610597565b005b61022e610612565b60405161023b919061119f565b60405180910390f35b61025e60048036038101906102599190610f53565b6106a4565b60405161026b9190611184565b60405180910390f35b61028e60048036038101906102899190610f53565b61078f565b60405161029b9190611184565b60405180910390f35b6102be60048036038101906102b99190610ec0565b6107ad565b6040516102cb9190611301565b60405180910390f35b6060600380546102e390611465565b80601f016020809104026020016040519081016040528092919081815260200182805461030f90611465565b801561035c5780601f106103315761010080835404028352916020019161035c565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161033f57829003601f168201915b5050505050905090565b600061037a610373610834565b848461083c565b6001905092915050565b6000600254905090565b600061039b848484610a07565b6000600160008673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060006103e6610834565b73ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002054905082811015610466576040517f08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000815260040161045d90611241565b60405180910390fd5b61047a85610472610834565b85840361083c565b60019150509392505050565b60006012905090565b600061053161049c610834565b8484600160006104aa610834565b73ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060008873ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1681526020019081526020016000205461052c9190611353565b61083c565b6001905092915050565b61054c610546610834565b82610c88565b50565b60008060008373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168152602001908152602001600020549050919050565b60006105aa836105a5610834565b6107ad565b9050818110156105ef576040517f08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000081526004016105e690611261565b60405180910390fd5b610603836105fb610834565b84840361083c565b61060d8383610c88565b505050565b60606004805461062190611465565b80601f016020809104026020016040519081016040528092919081815260200182805461064d90611465565b801561069a5780601f1061066f5761010080835404028352916020019161069a565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161067d57829003601f168201915b5050505050905090565b600080600160006106b3610834565b73ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060008573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002054905082811015610770576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610767906112e1565b60405180910390fd5b61078461077b610834565b8585840361083c565b600191505092915050565b60006107a361079c610834565b8484610a07565b6001905092915050565b6000600160008473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060008373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002054905092915050565b600033905090565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1614156108ac576040517f08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000081526004016108a3906112c1565b60405180910390fd5b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16141561091c576040517f08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000815260040161091390611201565b60405180910390fd5b80600160008573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002060008473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168152602001908152602001600020819055508173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff167f8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925836040516109fa9190611301565b60405180910390a3505050565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff161415610a77576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610a6e906112a1565b60405180910390fd5b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff161415610ae7576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610ade906111c1565b60405180910390fd5b610af2838383610e5f565b60008060008573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002054905081811015610b78576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610b6f90611221565b60405180910390fd5b8181036000808673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002081905550816000808573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1681526020019081526020016000206000828254610c0b9190611353565b925050819055508273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff167fddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef84604051610c6f9190611301565b60405180910390a3610c82848484610e64565b50505050565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff161415610cf8576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610cef90611281565b60405180910390fd5b610d0482600083610e5f565b60008060008473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200190815260200160002054905081811015610d8a576040517f08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008152600401610d81906111e1565b60405180910390fd5b8181036000808573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168152602001908152602001600020819055508160026000828254610de191906113a9565b92505081905550600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff168373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff167fddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef84604051610e469190611301565b60405180910390a3610e5a83600084610e64565b505050565b505050565b505050565b600081359050610e7881611821565b92915050565b600081359050610e8d81611838565b92915050565b600060208284031215610ea957610ea86114f5565b5b6000610eb784828501610e69565b91505092915050565b60008060408385031215610ed757610ed66114f5565b5b6000610ee585828601610e69565b9250506020610ef685828601610e69565b9150509250929050565b600080600060608486031215610f1957610f186114f5565b5b6000610f2786828701610e69565b9350506020610f3886828701610e69565b9250506040610f4986828701610e7e565b9150509250925092565b60008060408385031215610f6a57610f696114f5565b5b6000610f7885828601610e69565b9250506020610f8985828601610e7e565b9150509250929050565b600060208284031215610fa957610fa86114f5565b5b6000610fb784828501610e7e565b91505092915050565b610fc9816113ef565b82525050565b6000610fda82611337565b610fe48185611342565b9350610ff4818560208601611432565b610ffd816114fa565b840191505092915050565b6000611015602383611342565b91506110208261150b565b604082019050919050565b6000611038602283611342565b91506110438261155a565b604082019050919050565b600061105b602283611342565b9150611066826115a9565b604082019050919050565b600061107e602683611342565b9150611089826115f8565b604082019050919050565b60006110a1602883611342565b91506110ac82611647565b604082019050919050565b60006110c4602483611342565b91506110cf82611696565b604082019050919050565b60006110e7602183611342565b91506110f2826116e5565b604082019050919050565b600061110a602583611342565b915061111582611734565b604082019050919050565b600061112d602483611342565b915061113882611783565b604082019050919050565b6000611150602583611342565b915061115b826117d2565b604082019050919050565b61116f8161141b565b82525050565b61117e81611425565b82525050565b60006020820190506111996000830184610fc0565b92915050565b600060208201905081810360008301526111b98184610fcf565b905092915050565b600060208201905081810360008301526111da81611008565b9050919050565b600060208201905081810360008301526111fa8161102b565b9050919050565b6000602082019050818103600083015261121a8161104e565b9050919050565b6000602082019050818103600083015261123a81611071565b9050919050565b6000602082019050818103600083015261125a81611094565b9050919050565b6000602082019050818103600083015261127a816110b7565b9050919050565b6000602082019050818103600083015261129a816110da565b9050919050565b600060208201905081810360008301526112ba816110fd565b9050919050565b600060208201905081810360008301526112da81611120565b9050919050565b600060208201905081810360008301526112fa81611143565b9050919050565b60006020820190506113166000830184611166565b92915050565b60006020820190506113316000830184611175565b92915050565b600081519050919050565b600082825260208201905092915050565b600061135e8261141b565b91506113698361141b565b9250827fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0382111561139e5761139d611497565b5b828201905092915050565b60006113b48261141b565b91506113bf8361141b565b9250828210156113d2576113d1611497565b5b828203905092915050565b60006113e8826113fb565b9050919050565b60008115159050919050565b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff82169050919050565b6000819050919050565b600060ff82169050919050565b60005b83811015611450578082015181840152602081019050611435565b8381111561145f576000848401525b50505050565b6000600282049050600182168061147d57607f821691505b60208210811415611491576114906114c6565b5b50919050565b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052601160045260246000fd5b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052602260045260246000fd5b600080fd5b6000601f19601f8301169050919050565b7f45524332303a207472616e7366657220746f20746865207a65726f206164647260008201527f6573730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a206275726e20616d6f756e7420657863656564732062616c616e60008201527f6365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a20617070726f766520746f20746865207a65726f20616464726560008201527f7373000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a207472616e7366657220616d6f756e742065786365656473206260008201527f616c616e63650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a207472616e7366657220616d6f756e742065786365656473206160008201527f6c6c6f77616e6365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a206275726e20616d6f756e74206578636565647320616c6c6f7760008201527f616e636500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a206275726e2066726f6d20746865207a65726f2061646472657360008201527f7300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a207472616e736665722066726f6d20746865207a65726f20616460008201527f6472657373000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a20617070726f76652066726f6d20746865207a65726f2061646460008201527f7265737300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b7f45524332303a2064656372656173656420616c6c6f77616e63652062656c6f7760008201527f207a65726f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000602082015250565b61182a816113dd565b811461183557600080fd5b50565b6118418161141b565b811461184c57600080fd5b5056fea2646970667358221220b427c32695fede61ba4b1f99f7a281c5407aa2a126fd359b86ddf33e6afd646964736f6c63430008070033",
"linkReferences": {},
"name": "",
"inputs": "(string,string,uint256,address)",
"type": "constructor",
"from": "account{0}"
}
}
],
"abis": {
"0x55507316a2ecd9b9a32d4209f43d612bbce4b1cca44a7e1b861fa3b3fcce0de5": [
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "string",
"name": "name",
"type": "string"
},
{
"internalType": "string",
"name": "symbol",
"type": "string"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "initialSupply",
"type": "uint256"
},
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "owner",
"type": "address"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "constructor"
},
{
"anonymous": false,
"inputs": [
{
"indexed": true,
"internalType": "address",
"name": "owner",
"type": "address"
},
{
"indexed": true,
"internalType": "address",
"name": "spender",
"type": "address"
},
{
"indexed": false,
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "value",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "Approval",
"type": "event"
},
{
"anonymous": false,
"inputs": [
{
"indexed": true,
"internalType": "address",
"name": "from",
"type": "address"
},
{
"indexed": true,
"internalType": "address",
"name": "to",
"type": "address"
},
{
"indexed": false,
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "value",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "Transfer",
"type": "event"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "owner",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "spender",
"type": "address"
}
],
"name": "allowance",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "spender",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "amount",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "approve",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "bool",
"name": "",
"type": "bool"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "account",
"type": "address"
}
],
"name": "balanceOf",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "amount",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "burn",
"outputs": [],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "account",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "amount",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "burnFrom",
"outputs": [],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "decimals",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "uint8",
"name": "",
"type": "uint8"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "spender",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "subtractedValue",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "decreaseAllowance",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "bool",
"name": "",
"type": "bool"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "spender",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "addedValue",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "increaseAllowance",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "bool",
"name": "",
"type": "bool"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "name",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "string",
"name": "",
"type": "string"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "symbol",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "string",
"name": "",
"type": "string"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "totalSupply",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "recipient",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "amount",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "transfer",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "bool",
"name": "",
"type": "bool"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "sender",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "address",
"name": "recipient",
"type": "address"
},
{
"internalType": "uint256",
"name": "amount",
"type": "uint256"
}
],
"name": "transferFrom",
"outputs": [
{
"internalType": "bool",
"name": "",
"type": "bool"
}
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
}
]
}
}

ABI Encoded for this source contract 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000115eec47f6cf7e3500000000000000000000000000000020938d8bd8a69f544aa4a72392aa8d09d8f7e109000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a7472616365726f75746520776f6b655f6d696e645f766972757300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055472616365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: to keep the question easy to understand I would recommend to move some of the details (e.g. the deployment data, bytecode and abi) to an external file (e.g. gist or hackmd)